# Qsort with Huffman tree

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree, huffman-code, qsort

I have a problem where I have to build a Huffman tree, I understand the concept behind the problem and I know how to do it. However, I have discovered the reason for my code going wrong is to do with my sorting functions. I want to sort the list every time I input a new node into the list. I have a structure and in it I have frequency, I have made an array of structures that character are store in from a file.

My problem lies with creating the nodes, a new node is created and points to two characters in the array. However, when I then sort this list the pointers change to other characters. This happens for every step and causes it to be completely wrong.

My qsort call in main is like this:

```
qsort(list, n, sizeof(Node), intcompare);
```

and my intcompare function is like this:

```
int intcompare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
int freq1 = ((Node*)a)->frequency;
int freq2 = ((Node*)b)->frequency;

   if (freq1 == freq2){
      return 0;
   }
   else if (freq1 < freq2){
      return 1;
   }
   else{
      return -1;
   }

}
```

my structure is like this:

```
typedef struct node{
   char character;
   int frequency;
   struct node *left;
   struct node *right;
}Node;
```

My list gets sorted correctly by frequency each time I call qsort.
Why would this change where the pointers in my struct are pointing to?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`qsort` moves the structures around in the array. So if there exists a `left` pointer that points to character `X` at index 3 in the array, and `qsort` moves `X` to index 16, then the `left` pointer won't be pointing at `X` anymore. It will be pointing to whatever `qsort` put at index 3. Long story short, you need to recompute all of the `left` and `right` pointers after every sort.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That makes a lot of sense, when I create a node with 2 leaves, I'm supposed to delete those leaves from the list, so that they're not used again. I do this by setting their frequency to 0 and then only consider the ones that have freq > 0. This seems like a bad way to do it.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of sorting the Node array, one could create an array of pointers to the `Node`s and sort *that*.

Comment: Thanks John, I was just thinking the same thing, create 2 arrays and keep one static :).

Comment: The other alternative is not to sort at all. The algorithm requires that you find the two lowest frequencies at each step. This can be done with a single pass through the array, keeping track of the two lowest frequencies seen. That's actually faster than sorting the array.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I have to insert the newly created node into the correct place of the list. I've been told to use an insertion sort, but I haven't ever used it before.

Comment: That is probably how I can do it actually, with the least changes. Rather than resorting the list each time I just put the new node in the correct place. I think that'll work with the indexing